# Growth or decay in complex valued nonlinear ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have a system that takes the form

$$\dot{A}+\gamma_1A^2+\gamma_2|A|^2+\gamma_3 (A^*)^2=0,$$

where $A=A(t)$ is a complex valued function, the dot represents a derivative with respect to t,$^*$ means complex conjugate, and $\gamma_i \in \mathbb{C}$. That is the coefficients $\gamma_i$ are given complex valued constants.

$\textbf{How do the relative signs and magnitudes of the $\gamma_i$ effect the evolution of $A$?}$

In particular I want to know about the behavior of $d |A|^2/dt$ and whether the system will grow or decay. Note, if I explicitly form the evolution equation for this quantity I do not get anything insightful out of it.